# Timeline problem with latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

My objective is to create a timeline with 5 different date (13.10.13, 01.05.14, 31.05.14, 05.06.14 and 10.06.14) with:
- a brace called "Estimation WIndow 200 days from 13.10.13 to 01.05.14
- a brace called "Event Window +/-5 days from 31.05.14 to 10.06.14
- a point on the 05.06.14 called "Event day"
the packages that I have uploades are:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,positioning, arrows.meta}
```

The code that I wroted is the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
% draw horizontal line   
\draw[thick, -Triangle] (0,0) -- (\ImageWidth,0) node[font=\scriptsize,below left=3pt and -8pt]{years};

% draw vertical lines
\foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
\draw (\x cm,3pt) -- (\x cm,-3pt);

\foreach \x/\descr in {4/t-2,5/t-1,6/t,7/t+1}
\node[font=\scriptsize, text height=1.75ex,
text depth=.5ex] at (\x,-.3) {$\descr$};

% draw node
\draw[ultra thick] (2,0) node[below=3pt,thick] {13.10.2013} node[above=3pt] {};
\draw[ultra thick] (3,0) node[below=3pt,thick] {01.05.2014} node[above=3pt] {};
\draw[ultra thick] (4,0) node[below=3pt,thick] {31.04.2014} node[above=3pt] {};
\draw[ultra thick] (5,0) node[below=3pt,thick] {05.06.2014} node[above=3pt] {};
\draw[ultra thick] (6,0) node[below=3pt, thick] {10.06.2014} node[above=3pt] {};



\draw [thick ,decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt}] (2,0.7)  -- +(3,0) 
       node [black,midway,above=4pt, font=\scriptsize] {Estimation Window 200 days};

\draw [thick ,decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt}] (4,0.7)  -- +(6,0) 
       node [black,midway,above=4pt, font=\scriptsize] {Event Window +/-5 days};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

The result that I obtain is:
[image]

What is the problem? Can someone help me?

Comment: How is `\ImageWidth` defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think it simple. This is my proposal for this case.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,positioning, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm,>=latex]
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (6,0) node[below,font=\scriptsize] {Date};
\draw (1,.1)--(1,-.1) node[below] {13.10.13};
\draw (2,.1)--(2,-.1) node[below] {01.05.14};
\draw (3,.1)--(3,-.1) node[below] {31.05.14};
\draw (4,.1)--(4,-.1) node[below] (x) {05.06.14};
\draw (5,.1)--(5,-.1) node[below] {10.06.14};
\draw[<->] (1,.5)--(2,.5) node[midway,above,font=\scriptsize] {Estimation Window 200 days};
\draw[<->] (3,.5)--(5,.5) node[midway,above,font=\scriptsize] {Event Window $\pm5$ days};
\draw[<-] (x.south) --++ (0,-1) node[below,font=\scriptsize] {Event day};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]